# fontFamily param seems to be ignored

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm facing very strange problem here:

I have EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:hint="@string/login_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"           
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>
```

as you see, there's `fontFamily = sans-serif-light` but when I install this build on device or emulator I got `roboto normal font`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: try to use android:typeface="blablabla" it will solve your problem ! :}

Comment: what api version are you running on? The roboto light font family is only available in jellybean (api 16) and above.

Comment: Someone edited my question.. Ok, Android version is 4.1.2 (API 16)

Comment: Ah it's in the tags. Jellybean - does it make sense?